Start spark-shell successful in one machine but failed in another machine
Both machine and the spark cluster are in the same local network.
I have one of my machine 0.0.0.99 already connected with the spark cluster.
Because of the business need, we have to use another machine 0.0.0.212 to connect to the spark cluster, both machine has the same software installed(same version hadoop, yarn,spark and scala), the only difference is the setting and configuration.
I copied the settings of
/etc/hosts(recording the spark01:ip1,spark02:ip2 ...etc, which is the mapping info of each machine name and their ip in spark cluster.), and /etc/profile(recording the JAVA_HOME, SPARKs,HADOOPs,YARNs environment var) to another machine 0.0.0.212; also copied the yarn-site.xml and spark-defaults.conf, respectively.
I run the command spark-shell on this new machine:which stop with error:
Invalid Spark URL: spark://YarnScheduler@tencent_r:40707 (tencent_r is my hostname)

I googled and find someone says the hostname can't include underscore(which may not be the problem since the old machine 99 also has host name with underscore:VM_99) But I still changed the hostname to tencentR. And start spark-shell again, which stops and returns with another error:JAVA.io.IOException:Failed to connect to tencentr:43372

My spark version is 2.4.7
My Scala version is 2.11.12
I am running spark in yarn mode.
And the hadoop and yarn runs properly (proved by if I run hadoop version, yarn version, both return me with correct info.)
If any one need the hadoop and yarn version, I will post here, but I don't think it is related.
FYI, the spark has run in the old machine 0.0.0.99 for many years and no any connection problem. So I think the software version etc is fine, but my settings may not.
Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

I fixed this issue by adding my line of host's info(host name without underscore) into each cluster node machine's /etc/hosts file:
ip hostname

And it could get connection to the cluster properly.
Seems the better way is directly use host's ip address, but I haven't figure out how to do it yet.
